# Recover from accidental folder move

Tags: windows-7, recovery

I use Windows 7.

Because it is so easy to accidentally drag and drop a folder inside another folder situated below or above it - and to not notice this, is there a way to tell Windows to listen to and to record these operations? perhaps an external tool.

This is particularly important when navigating the folders of an installed application. Accidentally moving the BIN or LIB folders to some peer folders can make the application unusable, and the problem can be pretty hard to track down.

Comment: Slow down and stop making accidents...signed RoadRunner

Comment: You could use some third party application like [FolderChangesViewUtility](https://www.howtogeek.com/205144/how-to-monitor-file-and-folder-changes-in-windows/). I think it would work.

Comment: Great! FolderChangesView is just what i needed. I think you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to immediately right click in the window you're in and choose **Undo** from the pop-up menu that appears, or press **CTRL+Z**. Thus, your moving will be undone.

Comment: yes, that's a good hint, but it only works if I notice immediately the mistake that I done. But I might be unaware of the move, restart my PC, and some other day wonder why some application is no longer working. What I need is a log of the windows operations that I did, such as moving a folder

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing.